# String[][] - is groupBy() possible?

Tags: groovy, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to do **groupBy()** on the first element in a multidimensional String array?

```
String[][] serversAndQueues = [["server1","queue"],["server1","queue1"],["server2","queue2"]]
```

**each works..**

```
serversAndQueues.each{r->
    println r[0]
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
server1
server1
server2
```

**What about groupBy() ?**

```
serversAndQueues.groupBy( { it[0]}).each{r->
    println r[0]
}
```

**.. it throws an exeption**

**OUTPUT**

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [[Ljava.lang.String;.groupBy() is applicable for argument types: (ConsoleScript12$_run_closure2) values: [ConsoleScript12$_run_closure2@1e5182f]
Possible solutions: grep(), grep(), drop(int), countBy(groovy.lang.Closure), grep(java.lang.Object), grep(java.lang.Object)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does -- at least it does with Groovy 2.2.X:

```
String[][] serversAndQueues = [["server1","queue"],["server1","queue1"],["server2","queue2"]]

serversAndQueues.groupBy { it[ 0 ] }.each { key, value ->
    println "$key => $value"
}
```

Prints:

```
server1 => [[server1, queue], [server1, queue1]]
server2 => [[server2, queue2]]
```